# Unfortunately Appname has stopped, newbie

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, apk

I am a newbie when it comes to android development. I tried to run a project in emulator but i got a message saying "Unfortunately Appname has stopped". I am not sure what is wrong, if you guys can help it would be really great. Step by step guide would be much appreciated.

Here is the log file

```
    07-02 10:42:52.114: D/AndroidRuntime(2219): Shutting down VM
    07-02 10:42:52.114: W/dalvikvm(2219): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{brewedapps.app55/com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity" on path: /data/app/brewedapps.app55-1.apk
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity" on path: /data/app/brewedapps.app55-1.apk
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    07-02 10:42:52.134: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     ... 11 more
    07-02 10:42:56.068: I/Process(2219): Sending signal. PID: 2219 SIG: 9
    07-02 10:43:39.584: E/Trace(2247): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    07-02 10:43:39.674: D/AndroidRuntime(2247): Shutting down VM
    07-02 10:43:39.674: W/dalvikvm(2247): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{brewedapps.app55/com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity" on path: /data/app/brewedapps.app55-1.apk
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity" on path: /data/app/brewedapps.app55-1.apk
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    07-02 10:43:39.704: E/AndroidRuntime(2247):     ... 11 more
```

updated log file:

```
07-02 14:06:12.944: E/Trace(780): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-02 14:06:13.133: D/AndroidRuntime(780): Shutting down VM
07-02 14:06:13.133: W/dalvikvm(780): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.koutymony.webview/com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity" on path: /data/app/com.koutymony.webview-2.apk
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity" on path: /data/app/com.koutymony.webview-2.apk
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-02 14:06:13.153: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  ... 11 more
```

Here is the code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:versionCode="1" 
 android:versionName="1.0" 
 android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
 package="brewedapps.app55">

<uses-sdk 
   android:minSdkVersion="8" 
   android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
<activity 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name="com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
<activity android:name="com.appbrain.AppBrainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
<service android:name="com.appbrain.AppBrainService" />
<receiver android:name="com.appbrain.ReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did your project compile? Also, if you could share the code of `WebViewActivity` it will be great.

Comment: as logcat tells you it's related to com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity. check your manifest file for it's definition

Comment: Sorry, just a pointer: Have you seen the `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity" on path: /data/app/brewedapps.app55-1.apk` in the log? That seems to be the main problem. Looks like somewhere your apk generation is broken and does not include the needed classes at the right location.

Comment: The activity was named in a wrong way or its not decalted in manifest , try to post your manifest.xml here

Comment: Do you find the solution @Noura Yehia

Comment: not yet, i pasted the code in manifest file in my question for you guys to check

Answer (score 3):

Please declare this class `com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` inside of `<application><application/>`as below:

```
<activity android:name="brewedapps.app55.WebViewActivity"/>
```

### Edited Full Manifest File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:versionCode="1" 
 android:versionName="1.0" 
 android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
 package="brewedapps.app55">

<uses-sdk 
   android:minSdkVersion="8" 
   android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
<activity 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name="brewedapps.app55.WebViewActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
<activity android:name="com.appbrain.AppBrainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
<service android:name="com.appbrain.AppBrainService" />
<receiver android:name="com.appbrain.ReferrerReceiver" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and your Application's Package should look like the below image:

[image]

**PackageName:** brewedapps.app55
**Class Name:** WebViewActivity.java

Comment: I pasted the code in manifest file in my question, can you please check and tell me what am i doing wrong

Comment: I just formatted your xml @NouraYehia.. Please change the Package name to `com.koutymony.webview` from `brewedapps.app55` in `manifest` tag if your `WebViewActivity` class is in the package `com.koutymony.webview`....

Comment: can you paste the complete code of the manifest file after fixing the wrong values cause i am not able to get your point.

Comment: please see my edited log file after running the app using your code

Answer (score 0):

It should look like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.yourpackage"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: since he said he is a newbie I wanted to give him the full manifestfile. It often is really frustrating to get this small codesnipets which are right but you don't know where to put them.
If he accepts your answer as the right one I will UPVOTE you...

Answer (score 0):

Declare your activity in Manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.koutymony.webview.WebViewActivity">
</activity>
```